# CakePHP routes of v3.1.1 don't work with v3.1.2, maybe wrong conventions?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, conventions

I update my cakePHP application from v3.1.1 to v3.1.2 and in this passage all my routes and file naming broke.

with **v3.1.1**:

> db_table = hotels_profiles (1to1 its correctly call it in this way if
>   i have 'hotels' table?)
>
> ModelTable = HotelsProfilesTable
>
> Entity = HotelsProfile
>
> Controller = HotelsProfilesController (for call model $this->Hotelsprofiles)
>
> url = /hotelsprofiles/action

Now with **v3.1.2** i need to rename:

> Controller to Hotelsprofiles, or change my url to hotels_profiles.
>
> In controller for call model i need to rename
>
> $this->Hotelsprofiles to $this->HotelsProfiles.

Why? What happended? I write the cake convention in wrong mode?

Please can you tell me, **in which mode i need to naming files in right way if i want to add a profile to hotels table?**

Comment: @AD7six yes, you right, my 3.1.1 is on windows localy, and the 3.1.2 are remote on linux. Thankyou very much! Now i understood my conventions is wrong i need to rename some things. Thank you again! Have a nice day! If you wont answer with right convention naming i check your answer how the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Upgrading isn't the cause of the problem

> url = /hotelsprofiles/action

This url will, by default, look for the file:

```
src/Controller/HotelsprofilesController.php
```

The file is named correctly according to the question:

```
src/Controller/HotelsProfilesController.php
                     ^
```

That url will still work on a case-insensitive file system (windows, osx) - but will fail on a case-sensitive file system (linux).

So the cause of the problem is not upgrading, but comparing windows (version 3.1.1) to not-windows (3.1.2 - but the version isn't relevant).

### Correct filenames

The [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) are detailed in the docs, though it's easier for new starters to simply use bake to ensure files and boilerplate code matches CakePHP's expectations:

```
-> bin/cake bake all HotelsProfiles

Welcome to CakePHP v3.1.2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/
PHP : 5.5.15-1~dotdeb.1
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake All
---------------------------------------------------------------
One moment while associations are detected.

Baking table class for HotelsProfiles...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Model/Table/HotelsProfilesTable.php
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Model/Table/HotelsProfilesTable.php`

Baking entity class for HotelsProfile...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Model/Entity/HotelsProfile.php
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Model/Entity/HotelsProfile.php`

Baking test fixture for HotelsProfiles...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/tests/Fixture/HotelsProfilesFixture.php
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/tests/Fixture/HotelsProfilesFixture.php`
Bake is detecting possible fixtures...

Baking test case for App\Model\Table\HotelsProfilesTable ...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/HotelsProfilesTableTest.php
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/tests/TestCase/Model/Table/HotelsProfilesTableTest.php`

Baking controller class for HotelsProfiles...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Controller/HotelsProfilesController.php
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Controller/HotelsProfilesController.php`
Bake is detecting possible fixtures...

Baking test case for App\Controller\HotelsProfilesController ...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/tests/TestCase/Controller/HotelsProfilesControllerTest.php
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/tests/TestCase/Controller/HotelsProfilesControllerTest.php`

Baking `index` view file...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/index.ctp
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/index.ctp`

Baking `view` view file...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/view.ctp
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/view.ctp`

Baking `add` view file...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/add.ctp
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/add.ctp`

Baking `edit` view file...

Creating file /var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/edit.ctp
Wrote `/var/www/cakephp.dev/src/Template/HotelsProfiles/edit.ctp`
Bake All complete.
```

In this way conventions are taken care for you, and not just the file name conventions:

```
...
$this->set('hotelsProfiles', $this->paginate($this->HotelsProfiles));
                                                          ^
...
```

You may not need the baked code - but using bake will answer many of your questions simply by looking at or using the baked code. Note the differences to the question:

- `$this->HotelsProfiles`
- Generated urls will by default be of the form `/hotels-profiles/view/1` - though the exact form depends on the default route class which is [configured in the routes file](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/routes.php#L24-L42).